# Where's the man page for the `sizeof` C function?

Tags: linux, c, man

How come there's no man page for the `sizeof` C function?

```
$ man 3 sizeof
No manual entry for sizeof in section 3

$ man sizeof
No manual entry for sizeof
```

I do see man pages for other C functions like `malloc` if I run `man 3 malloc` and similar commands, but nothing for `sizeof`.

Comment: why do you want to see Linux man page for a C thing? Unless it's a POSIX-related thing, reading from a standard document is better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**sizeof** isn't a function. it's an operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Comment: Is operator another word for macro?  What does operator exactly mean?

Comment: No. A macro is some text (not reserved word, nor operator, nor function) interpreted by the precompiler and expanded into something that can be compiled. Operators look like functions, but they are part of the language itself. Functions usually are part of a library. For a detailed explanation read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)

Comment: Thanks.  Last question: Is there an official documentation for operators like this?

Comment: Yes. The C language specification: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf - Check section 6.5.x

Answer (score 3):

You can use `man -wK 'sizeof' | sort -u` to find the articles that contain `sizeof`, but that'll return a lot of results. However notice that every article about something will have that thing as a bareword surrounded by spaces, we'll search for the article like this `zgrep -P '\ssizeof\s' /usr/share/man/man3/*`. But searching in section 3 doesn't give any useful information, so I'll search in section 7

```
$ zgrep -P '\ssizeof\s' /usr/share/man/man7/*
/usr/share/man/man7/inotify.7.gz:        len = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
/usr/share/man/man7/operator.7.gz:! ~ ++ \-\- + \- (type) * & sizeof    right to left
```

As you can see, the `sizeof` is mentioned in the operator man page, because [it's not a function but an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1393582/995714) and it works even without parentheses for identifiers like `sizeof buf` above

```
OPERATOR(7)               Linux Programmer's Manual              OPERATOR(7)

NAME         top

       operator - C operator precedence and order of evaluation

DESCRIPTION         top

       This manual page lists C operators and their precedence in
       evaluation.

       Operator                            Associativity
       () [] -> .                          left to right
       ! ~ ++ -- + - (type) * & sizeof     right to left
       * / %                               left to right
       + -                                 left to right
       << >>                               left to right
       < <= > >=                           left to right
       == !=                               left to right
       &                                   left to right
       ^                                   left to right
       |                                   left to right
       &&                                  left to right
       ||                                  left to right
       ?:                                  right to left
       = += -= *= /= %= <<= >>= &= ^= |=   right to left
       ,                                   left to right
```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/operator.7.html